# Empty paragraph passed to '@param' command

Tags: objective-c, xcode

When I edit an annotation of method, it shows warning on the annotation line, and it didn't show on the other file which I edit the annotation use the same way.
I wonder how it happened and how to solve this warning.

[image: that warning]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the description:

```
* @param success description of param here removes warning
```

Answer (score 0):

With warning:

```
/**
 * @param command 
 *
 * The callback id used when calling back into JavaScript.
 */
```

Without warning:

```
/**
 * @param command 
 * The callback id used when calling back into JavaScript.
 */
```